# low number divide by high number is not working

Tags: python

I have two numbers:

```
a = 4
b = 1166
```

when I am doing:

```
print(a/b)
```

It is showing output :`0`

Can you help me why is is not showing exact result?

Comment: Are you using Python 2 or 3?

Comment: @MrPolywhirl. No, don't. Read the post you suggested first yourself. This is purely a py2 issue. Try a=4.0 instead

Comment: @MadPhysicist thank man... by mentioning a and b as float. It worked.